# Find a vector V that is parallel to the reflection of a matrix about a line.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, reflection

Specific Question:

Let $M=(1/53)⋅[[45, 28], [28,-45]]$. M is the matrix of the reflection 
about a line. Find a vector v of magnitude (53)^0.5 parallel to that line.

Currently in class we are dealing with eigenvalues and eigenvectors. From the matrix M I found the Eigenvalues to be 53 and -53. I then used the equation M*U=U*D, and then simplified it to get Det(M-/lambda*I)*U=0. Using that equation I was able to get my eigenvectors which are [[98, 28],[28, 8]]. I was able to find an answer by finding the lowest common denominator of the first row of the matrix I just found. This would be [7,2].

I was able to find an answer on the homework problems by just looking for a pattern in the problem and answer sets. However, I really am not sure what I did, or whether its a valid solution or not.

Comment: What is your inner product?

Comment: Ah so the inner product would be the eigenvalue of 53. Would I then subtract M from [[53,0],[0,53]] to find my eigenvectors?

Comment: @user001 first of all, the inner product is by default the dot-product.  Second of all, inner products aren't necessarily relevant; the line is necessarily in the direction of the eigenvector for $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: So from what you're saying, λ=1, so M-λ*I would just be [[45,28],[28,-45]]-[[1,0],[0,1]]=0? I was able to find the answer from [[45,28],[28,-45]]-[[53,0],[0,53]]=[[98,28],[28,8]] where λ=53. I found V by reducing the first row of the resultant matrix by the lowest common denominator where v=[7,2]. My intuition is that my solution won't work in all cases however.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Yogi Berra is asking to find a vector of a certain magnitude (norm) -- how could he or she possibly *compute* this norm without the inner product?  You're saying, in quite a patronizing way, that the inner product *isn't relevant* here, which is bizarre.